How to toggle visibility of two password fields with one toggle in Android XML using Kotlin?
I have two password fields one is password another is confirm password. I want to use only one toggle in password field EditText using TextInputLayout's property passwordToggleEnabled="true". How can I programatically toggle the view of both fields when toggle button in password EditText is pressed.

I solved it with this code. Not sure whether the best approach if anyone know how to do it the proper way please let me know.
 binding.passwordET.addTextChangedListener {
       binding.confirmPasswordET.transformationMethod = binding.passwordET.transformationMethod
   }

